# tailwind how to display a layout based on breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to display a layout for a page that's dependent on it being the width of a phone. If it's screen width, I want to display cards else, a table. Does anyone know how to do this using tailwind's breakpoints? Until now I've been using window.innerwidth, but it's not working and I think it's a bad approach.

Here's what I have:

```
if (window.innerWidth > 600) {
  content = <DataTable columns={columns} data={data} />;
} else {
  console.log(window.innerWidth);
  content = <p>insert cards here...</p>;
}
```

And then ofc, I'm rendering content like so:

```
  <>
    <div className="text-[35px] text-neutral-900">
      Welcome back,{" "}
      <span className="font-semibold text-[50px] text-black">
        {currentUser.name}
      </span>
    </div>
    <div className="text-[25px] text-zinc-400 font-extralight">
      Here are your reminders...
    </div>
    {content}
  </>
```

I was thinking making the the cards invisible until it reaches a breakpoint, so rendering both, but that also doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [react-use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use) for getting a CSS media query.

```
import {useMedia} from 'react-use';

const App = () => {
  const isWide = useMedia('(min-width: 600px)');

  const content = isWide ? (
    <DataTable columns={columns} data={data} />
  ) : (
    <p>insert cards here...</p>
  )

  return (
    <>
      {/* YOUR CODE */}
      {content}
    </>
  );
};
```

You can get more idea from its [documentation](https://streamich.github.io/react-use/?path=/story/sensors-usemedia--docs)

If you don't like this hook, then there is no other way than rendering both elements.

```
const content = (
  <>
    <div className='hidden sm:block'>
      <DataTable columns={columns} data={data} />
    </div>
    <div className='block sm:hidden'>
      <p>insert cards here...</p>
    </div>
  </>
)
```

Before adding above, you need to override default screen breakpoints at tailwind.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'sm': '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 600px) { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

Take a look at here. [Configuring custom screens](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#configuring-custom-screens)

Answer (score 2):

Yes tailwind has breakpoints same as CSS media queries.

But the tailwind breakpoints are pre-defined eg: sm is 640px you can have a look at all breakpoints and their values in their docs [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design). You can Override the defaults as mentioined in this [section](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#overriding-the-defaults)

Also I saw you are using arbitrary values like `text-[35px]`. Tailwind encourages everyone to use their pre-defined values eg: `text-4xl`. This is done to maintain UI consistency.

Comment: Also upvoted this because of the great info on font-size!